# Short key to code suggestion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut

I found that it is useful to generate code by using suggestions:

[image]

But open suggestion list by pressing lamp takes too many time. Is it possible to achieve this list by short key combination?

Answer (score 6):

You can access that menu by clicking:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

(Hover over the light bulb to see the options available with your settings)

Comment: Shift + Alt + F10 didn't work for me, ALT and Enter worked to bring up the lamp menu (I have resharper installed and VS 2017)

Comment: See my update. It might depend on your configuration @Fuzzybear

Answer (score 0):

I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> which also works.

Comment: That is already in an existing answer which was posted minutes ago. Your answer doesn't add anything new.

Comment: Your initial post did not include ctrl . so you must have edited it after I began my response. I'm sorry to have offended you mr Patrick Hofman.

Comment: You didn't offend me, it just doesn't add anything new.

Comment: offended you enough to respond to my post :P